# Can't get Django to serve static files

Tags: python, django

**I know there are a ton of similiar threads on SO with actually the same question - but I can't solve my problem**

Django Version

```
>>> import django
>>> print django.get_version()
1.6.2
```

I want to access static files (css, images, ..) from a template.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
```

My folder structure

```
Project
|-- Project
    |-- settings.py
    |-- ...
|-- app
    |-- views.py
    |-- ...
|-- templates
    |-- a_template.html
|-- static
    |-- styles.css
```

settings.py (important parts)

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'server',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I tried a lot different solutions for `STATIC_URL` (even absolute paths) but none of them worked for me.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development, The documentation explains how to serve static files in development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, I would use the `static` template tag by adding to the top of the template:

```
{% load static %}
```

and then, in the href:

```
href="{% static "styles.css" %}"
```

then, I would change my `urls.py` and add the possibility for your development server to serve static files:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

/* you url patterns here */

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

that should do the trick...

Comment: still "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1634

Comment: have you tried adding `STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/path/to/your/static/folder/')` to your `settings.py`?
you have to use forward-slashes though, even on windows.

Comment: Nope - but now it works :) btw: I don't have to change the `urls.py`

Answer (score 1):

### Locating the static files

Since your `static` dir doesn't live in an app, you should add `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` to [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS). Much like you probably added `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` to your [TEMPLATE_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs). (at least I think so, as you're not complaining about missing templates.

### Collecting the static files (not needed during dev)

During [deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#deployment) you should issue a

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

command, which copies all static files to your `STATIC_ROOT`

### Using the static files in your template

To point your browser to the right resource you should either put `{{ STATIC_URL }}` before the filenames you use or use the [{% static %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) templatetags as in the [how to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files).

Answer (score 1):

Configure BASE_DIR:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

> Set Debug is True:

```
DEBUG=True
```

> Set Static URl:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Set ROOT_PATH  In ROOT variable

```
ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Set STATICFILES Variable:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

> Mention the Static css file in HTML file:

```
 {% load static %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the href attribute in the template:

```
href="{{STATIC_URL}}styles.css"
```

Additionally, you may want to collect static files via `python manage.py collectstatic`.

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Edited with the `collectstatic` tip, and documentation

Answer (score 0):

To get django to serve bootstrap files, I had to let collectstatic put the files into my STATIC_ROOT--I could NOT paste the files into the folder myself. I put the bootstrap files in a directory called my_app/boot.

updated my settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'boot'),
        ]
```

and ran

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```